# Electronic transition of iodine and non-bonding orbitals

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry

As you all know, iodine has a purple color when in the vapor phase and when dissolved in non-coordinating solvents such as carbon tetrachloride. What electronic transition is responsible for this?

A quick google search (https://www.vedantu.com/question-answer/the-color-of-iodine-is-a-violet-b-green-c-white-class-11-chemistry-cbse-5f4a918f84fe9e109c4b5753) says that this electron transition is due to non-bonding electrons going into the antibonding sigma orbital.

This is certainly possible, but leads me to a more general question: Usually, we don’t draw the non-bonding orbitals into the MO-scheme of the molecule. Take a look at the fluorine molecule for example (as its MO scheme should be similar than that of iodine):

[image]

Fluorine also has lone pairs, and they also could transition electronically; why don’t we write them out specifically and how does one know when they will be involved in electronic transitions?

For example, in carbonyls, there is also the n-pi* transition for reference,in which the non-bonding electrons of oxygen can be promoted to an antibonding orbital. Why don’t they participate in the MO scheme?

Comment: Electrons from lower orbitals (higher bonding energy) will transition to higher orbitals (lower bonding energy) when excited (by whatever...). Even forbidden transitions occur because atoms (or molecules) in the real world aren't totally isolated. Thus microstate perturbations allow "forbidden transitions," but they are relatively low in probability. *The rub here is not all of the transitions (excitation or emission) occur in the visible band.*

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Lone pairs and electrons in non-bonding orbitals are not the same thing

Comment: @IanBush how come it is not the same? For example in carbonyls, the oxygen electron pairs are the cause of the non-bonding-pi* transition: https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2016/09/26/uv-vis-spectroscopy-absorbance-of-carbonyls/

Comment: @MaxW true but where are non-bonding electrons located, exactly, in the MO? Should be somewhere, if they are available for a transition, like the n-pi* transition in carbonyls (see link in last comment)

Comment: In this source, they also mention non-bonding (n) electrons of the carbonyls for n-pi*-transitions: https://szerves.chem.elte.hu/oktatas/ea/Perczel/UV-VIS.pdf IMO, in MO schemes non-bonding electrons are not highlighted though.

Comment: I2 has the ground state configuration $(\sigma_g5p)^2(\pi_u5p)^4(\pi^*_g5p)^4(\sigma^*_u5p)^0$ and the first excited state $(\sigma_g5p)^2(\pi_u5p)^4(\pi^*_g5p)^3(\sigma^*_u5p)^1$, so $\pi^* \to \sigma^*$. The transition is between states $^1\Sigma^+_g \,\to\,^3\Pi_u$ . As this molecule contains heavy atoms spin-orbit coupling is very important and the singlet - triplet spin transition prohibition is broken.

Comment: @Mäßige Your MO diagram for F2 *does* include the electrons which in another view of the world would be the lone pairs. Count the electrons, you have all 7 2s & 2p electrons for each F, so where are the electrons for the lone pairs? They *must* be already in that diagram! The problem is that you are mixing 2 different views of the world. In MO theory orbitals are across the whole molecule; MO theory is a totally delocalised view. Lone pairs are a localised concept and as such don't occur in MO theory. You can make the connection, but you have to a a lot more careful than you have in the above.

Comment: True @IanBush they have to be inside of there somewhere. So in actuality, iodine in an MO scheme doesn't have lone pairs per se, rather non bonding orbitals somewhere in it (namely the pi/pi* and sigma/sigma* (2s) orbitals). So the transition is due to pi* to sigma*, would you agree. Furthermore why would a carbonyl have nonbonding electrons then? Or is it a semi-quantitative MO scheme?

Comment: To be sure I would have to read up on this more, but my first guess would be as you say, pi* -> sigma* But the point @porphyrin makes about spin orbit coupling is important as well

Answer (score 2):

### Hybrid orbitals and molecular orbitals are different ways of looking at the same thing

Let’s take your fluorine example first.

It doesn’t quite make sense to ask why we “don’t write out the lone pairs specifically” in $\ce{F2}$; we’re using a different model. Once we’ve decided that the $1s$ electrons are core and won’t participate significantly in bonding, we have 14 electrons to worry about, *all of which are shown in the MO diagram*; there are no extra lone pairs that we’ve chosen to ignore.

Alternatively (but worse from the perspective of understanding electronic transitions), we could say that these 14 electrons are arranged in three lone pairs on each of two F atoms (3 pairs $\times$ 2 atoms $\times$ 2 electrons per pair = 12 electrons total) plus one $\sigma$ bond between the atoms (the final two electrons).

So it’s not that we’re choosing to ignore lone pairs, it’s that they don’t exist in this model.

### Non-bonding orbitals *are* typically included in MO diagrams

The link you gave to illustrate your carbonyl example only shows three orbitals. For a fuller picture, let’s have a look at a [qualitative MO diagram](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0082495X07800229) for the simplest carbonyl compound, formaldehyde:

[image: Qualitative MO diagram for H2CO, shown in terms of interactions between CO and H2]

(This diagram has some flaws but it was the best I could find quickly online.)

The LUMO, here given the symmetry label $2b_1$, is an example of an orbital conventionally labelled “non-bonding”, though in fact you can see that it is mildly antibonding between C and O and bonding between C and H. There’s a more quantitative picture [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Formaldehyde_Molecular_Orbitals.jpg). The point is that we don’t have to decide whether or not to include this; it turns up naturally when we make the diagram.

### The visible transition in $\ce{I2}$ is better thought of as being between two antibonding orbitals

Returning to your initial question, as your own MO diagram and several comments have indicated, the HOMO-LUMO transition in $\ce{I2}$ is best described as $\pi^*\rightarrow\sigma^*$, not $n\rightarrow\sigma^*$. The source you link to for the latter description is not very scholarly! As the comments have pointed out, the reason for iodine’s strong colour includes both that this transition occurs in the visible spectrum and that spin-orbit coupling breaks the “selection rule” prohibiting a singlet-triplet transition.